# How to get the proxy used for each request in scrapy logs?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using a custom proxy middleware for rotating proxies and I would like to get a log  for the proxy used for each request:

```
packetstream_proxies = [
    settings.get("PS_PROXY_USA"),
    settings.get("PS_PROXY_CA"),
    settings.get("PS_PROXY_IT"),
    settings.get("PS_PROXY_GLOBAL"),
]

unlimited_proxies = [
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_1"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_2"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_3"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_4"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_5"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_6"),
]


class SdtProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # retries = request.meta.get("retry_times", 0)
        request.meta["proxy"] = random.choice(packetstream_proxies)
        if request.meta.get("retry_times") == 1:
            request.meta["proxy"] = random.choice(unlimited_proxies)
            return None

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):

        spider.logger.info(
            f"""Processed {response.url} with {request.meta.get("proxy")}"""
        )
        return response
```

I tried to log in `process_response` like this:

```
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):

        spider.logger.info(
            f"""Processed {response.url} with {request.meta.get("proxy")}"""
        )
        return response
```

but it is working for some URLs like this `Processed https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/c/men/apparel with http://proxyserver:8884` and most of the time it is `Processed https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/c/women-s-apparel?start=168&sz=24 with None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the latest versions of scrapy: HttpProxy middleware - delete proxy meta data from `request.meta['proxy']` after updating requests [scrapy source related code lines](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blame/2.8.0/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpproxy.py#L66-L67)

As result of this You receive `None` values on log entries from `process_response`

This change applied to scrapy several months ago due to security issue mentioned on:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-2-6-2-2022-07-25
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9x8m-2xpf-crp3

Update
Applying proxy logging can be implemented by middleware like this:

```
class ProxyLoggingMiddleware:
    process_request(self, request, spider):
        spider.logger.info(
            f"""Request {request.url} sent with {request.meta.get("proxy")}"""
        )
```

In settings

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    `pathto...SdtProxyMiddleware`: 0,
    `pathto...ProxyLoggingMiddleware`: 950
}
```

Comment: Got it! Is there any workaround to get the proxy used for each request in a log?

Comment: I'd add another ..`ProxyLogging` downloader middleware with `spider.logger.info(...` call in `process_request` method. It's `process_request` method should be called after `process_request` of HttpProxy middleware.

Comment: Can you please guide me through any working example for the above middleware you mentioned?

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Is there any way I can get a proxy from the response too?

Comment: In general it is possible only if proxy provider add specific headers to responses.  Also response object has `ip_address` field hovewer I don't know in details how it works with proxies